# Change popup format for Kopete in Gnome (Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-10.04, kopete

After trialling Empathy which was included with Gnome/Ubuntu 10.04 I decided to go back to Kopete since I was losing chat messages.

However, for some reason, Kopete is now displaying all popups in a big, ugly window with four options (ok, cancel, view, ignore, or something like that) that actually all seem to do nothing.

I tried looking for options in Kopete to change the popup style to the nicer Gnome style one which goes up in the top-right of my desktop, but it doesn't seem to be possible with this release. So I had to resort to removing all popup messages from Kopete to prevent my screen being taking over by a popup requiring action for every incoming chat message.

Unfortunately, this now means that I do not get any notifications when people message me - and so I can go a couple of hours without realising that they did.

Anyone know how to get the nice, unobtrusive popups working in this version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change notification settings in Kopete not to show popups. As for smart text popups - it seems we should wait for kopete's updates

Upd: yep, I was right. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236599

Comment: yeah, i've disabled popups in Kopete - but this makes it hard to know when there are messages pending. this is kinda annoying, since it worked right in 9.10